# Where is Microsoft Edge located in Windows 10? How do I launch it?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I have upgraded my laptop to Windows 10 Home. But I can't find the Microsoft Edge web browser.

Does anyone know where it is located, or do I need to install it?

---

**Update:** I could find `MicrosoftEdge.exe` at `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe`. But when I click on it, it doesn't run.

Comment: Where are you from? Do you perhaps have a K or N edition?

Comment: @DanielB, I am from **India** and I have **windows 10 Home** edition

Comment: The MicrosoftEdge.exe cannot be run like other programs. If you do not have the Microsoft Edge shortcut in the taskbar, search for it in the search bar or start menu. Then pin it to the taskbar.

Comment: How sure are you that the edge browser is not being run when you click the Internet Explorer like icon on your task bar? I believe it should be the default browser rather than the old IE.

Comment: @MC10, thanks. I followed your instruction and I could run Microsoft Edge. Before also I searched in search bar, but I did not find it. But now I unpin MicrosoftEdge.exe from start menu which I pinned previously and search for it in search bar. And now it is running.

Comment: @Mokubai, It was not running. I tried running internet explorer and it was running but it was not edge browser. By the way I got it running now. Thanks

Comment: @NamanGala Sounds good, glad you could get it working.

Comment: *"I have located the MicrosoftEdge.exe but it is not running when I am clicking on it."*  Congratulations! You have found it! But if you can't run it, then perhaps you should change the title of the question. Also, have you tried turning it off and on again? If you were too eager to start testing your new Windows and Edge, you might want to try a reboot first, after completing the upgrade. That might be helpful.

Comment: @sammyg that (reboot) I tried earlier but it did not change anything. And also I have updated my question.

Comment: Win+R > microsoft-edge:https://www.microsoft.com/microsoft-edge or Win+R > microsoft-edge:

Comment: anyone have a clue why MS insists on making its own executables hard to find?  i am just trying to open a PDF with Edge, but it's not on the suggested apps list for some reason and without a path, it's hard to browse for it.  They do the same with Office and a whole of other stuff, totally, utterly, pointless.

Comment: I just run iexplore on run  (year 2023). Works for me.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Outdated

This information is outdated. OP may not be around to switch the accepted answer. Please refer to answers from [Overmind](https://superuser.com/a/950457/403203) or [Yanzzee](https://superuser.com/a/1033271/403203), or [Europa's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/950435/where-is-microsoft-edge-located-in-windows-10-how-do-i-launch-it/950456#comment2516842_950456) for newer information.

## Old Answer

Microsoft Edge should be in the taskbar. It is the blue 'e' icon.

[image: Taskbar]

If you do not have that or have unpinned it, you just need to repin it. Unfortunately the `MicrosoftEdge.exe` can not be run by double clicking and creating a normal shortcut will not work. You may have found it at this location.

[image: Location]

What you need to do is just search for Edge in the Start menu or search bar. Once you see Microsoft Edge, right click on it and **Pin to taskbar**.

[image: Search]

Comment: There is a way to create a shortcut to Edge. Yanzzee below has what should be the correct answer.

Comment: May 2021: Edge is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe. It can be found by either goint to that location or shell:Appsfolder.

Answer (score 62):

Make a new shortcut for it

Correct link is:

```
%windir%\explorer.exe shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge
```

Then add it's icon from its own .exe if you don't like the default look.

```
 %windir%\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe
```

Comment: This is great. Is there anyway to pin an incognito version (private mode) to the taskbar?

Comment: Browsers can start in that mode with a specific parameter (Opera -newprivatetab, IE -private, Chrome -incognito). According to MS -private should work for Edge, but we'll have to test this.

Comment: Where do you see Microsoft suggesting -private will work for edge? Even so, how could that be passed via "explorer.exe shell:Appsfolder\Micr.... " which is the only known way to create a shortcut?

Comment: It's on their page.

Comment: Thanks, but "it's on their page" isn't helpful. I submit there's no currently known way to add a -private or any parameters to an Edge shortcut at this time. You can launch a site using "microsoft-edge:www.cnn.com" Or "%windir%\explorer.exe microsoft-edge:www.cnn.com" but I've found no way to add -private parameter.

Comment: +1 This worked great to get a shortcut. Is there anyway to open a specific web page this way? I've done it in the past with IE by adding the URL after the shortcut Target, but in this case that just opens up a file explorer window.

Comment: Edge works differently. For a specific page you can use the start command: start microsoft-edge:http://www.msn.com - this will open msn-dot-com.

Comment: Using cmd in the shortcut, you can start an private mode window, but you will see the cmd window for a very short time during startup: `%windir%\System32\cmd.exe /c start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge -private`

Answer (score 12):

To create a new shortcut from the existing shortcut file, you can also enter this path into file explorer:

```
shell:Appsfolder
```

Scroll to Microsoft Edge, then and drag or right click to create a new shortcut. I used this method to put Edge in the startup folder.

Comment: the shortcut is exactly the same as in @Overmind's answer

Comment: That's fair. However I'd rather use the GUI to create a GUI shortcut than the command line to create a GUI shortcut.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure when this changed, but in my version of Windows 10 (21H1 - 19043.1023) the executable for Edge is located in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe`

Comment: The author's question was specifically with regards to Legacy Edge, not Chromium Edge which has a different installation directory entirely.

Comment: That's not really clear from the question. I suppose it's implied based on the time it was asked. But this question is the top result on Google if you look up "where is Edge installed?". I'm pretty sure anyone looking for that today is asking about the Chromium version.

Comment: @nVitius - this is exactly what I was looking for - Having an answer for Chromium Edge is wonderful, even if this post was made _before_ Chromium Edge existed.  Google doesn't differentiate, and neither did this post.  Huzzah!

Answer (score 3):

You can launch Microsoft Edge in private mode by using this AutoHotkey-script:

```
^P::                
Run %windir%\explorer.exe shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge
Sleep 1000
Send ^+P
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Open With addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-with/) needs the command line to have the %s so that the currently open site gets launched in Edge.
`C:\Windows\explorer.exe "microsoft-edge:%s"`

Answer (score 0):

On my system, Microsoft Edge is really installed at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe
```

Create a shortcut as normal in Explorer. This loads much more quickly than the strange `%windir%\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe` re-direction.

The final shortcut has `Target` set to one of:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe`

or if you prefer:

`%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe`

Copy and strip off `\msedge.exe` for the `Start in` parameter of the shortcut.