# My Edge browser is gone Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

my Edge browser has disappeared from the task bar and need a fix. Does anyone have a solution that works? I have tried a couple of things listed but none work

Comment: What have you tried exactly?  Did you perform anything action that might have removed it?

Comment: Have you tried pinning it back onto the taskbar?

Comment: Does pressing Windows key and typing "Edge" yield anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is Microsoft Edge located in windows 10 or how to run Microsoft edge browser?](http://superuser.com/questions/950435/where-is-microsoft-edge-located-in-windows-10-or-how-to-run-microsoft-edge-brows)

Answer (score 2):

- Press WinKey
- Type "Edge" (right afterpressing WinKey, no more clicks)
- Click on the first icon on the right (Microsoft Edge)

Edge browser will be started.

- Right click on the Edge icon on the task bar
- Select "Pin this program to taskbar"

Profit!