# The MS Edge browser icon has disappeared from the Taskbar but I can still use it

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, start-menu, microsoft-edge

Under Windows 10 (obviously) the MS Edge browser icon has disappeared from the Taskbar. I can activate via an add-on in Firefox, so I can still use it. 
I can not reach it via Alt-Tab nor via the Task View button on the Taskbar.
I can only see it if I minimize all the windows that are on top of it or rather, active before it.
If it was merely unpinned from the Taskbar, I would see it whenever it was active and not when it was exited. But I don't see it, ever.

Also, hitting WinKey and typing edge does NOT startup MS Edge Browser. Only way to do so, is through the Firefox addon.

At the same time, the Start button Menu doesn't show the icons of the Programs (or apps) which I use a lot, in the rectangle thingee, idk what thats called. I just see the alphbetical vertical list of of all programs.

I found MicrosoftEdge.exe in the folder "C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe". Neither left nor right clicking did ANYTHING.

How do I fix this and get the taskbar button back?

PS. As a courtesy to me, please check before you insinuate that my question is already answered elsewhere, like here: [My Edge browser is gone Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/951313/my-edge-browser-is-gone-windows-10)
because it's not and that is a whole 'nother question.

Comment: If your going to use comments instead of updating your question I can't help.  Don't use those dashes in your question.

Comment: You can download the MS Edge shortcut from this page [link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7755-create-shortcut-microsoft-edge-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: @spike_66 Thanks, that's helpful

Comment: Your comment is breaking the page layout.  You should be updating the question, instead is submitting comments, that break the page layout.  It's also extremely hard to read, the dashes, don't help its readability

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is Microsoft Edge located in Windows 10? How do I launch it?](https://superuser.com/questions/950435/where-is-microsoft-edge-located-in-windows-10-how-do-i-launch-it). Specifically, check out [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/950457/23133)