# Windows 10, Microsoft Edge, Microsoft Natural Wireless Ergonomic Keyboard 7000, set-up

Tags: keyboard

When using the Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard center for the Microsoft Natural Wireless Ergonomic Keyboard 7000, I want to give the exact location of Microsoft Edge so that my Web/Home key on the 7000 will launch Edge.

I need the complete path to Microsoft Edge.  What is it?

Thank you,
Stephen Stubbs.

Answer (score 0):

The MicrosoftEdge.exe cannot be run like other programs so I am unsure if this will work. It can be located at

%windir%\explorer.exe shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge

This is a hidden folder so you will need to ensure that you are able to see these (edit this setting using a windows search for 'hidden folders'). It can be located through navigation in the program files folder.

Some info sourced from this thread: 
[Where is Microsoft Edge located in Windows 10? How do I launch it?](https://superuser.com/questions/950435/where-is-microsoft-edge-located-in-windows-10-or-how-to-launch-microsoft-edge-br)