# How to use Microsoft Edge in Sandboxie?

Tags: windows-10, browser, microsoft-edge

Surprisingly enough, none of the answers in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/950435/where-is-microsoft-edge-located-in-windows-10-how-do-i-launch-it/950457) seem to answer the question properly. It seems as though everyone is saying it's located in `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe`, but clicking on the `MicrosoftEdge.exe` in that folder does not open the program.

I am trying to run Microsoft Edge in Sandboxie. However, I'm finding it quite challenging because it seems as though I can only do that with a direct link to the `.exe` file. Is there any location for the `.exe` which I can press and run, so that I can open it with Sandboxie? I don't want to change my default browser.

Comment: The linked question _is_ answered properly. The accepted answer even says "Unfortunately the MicrosoftEdge.exe can not be run by double clicking and creating a normal shortcut will not work.". So the location is right, you're just expecting it to work in a way that it doesn't. :)

Comment: I see, now I understand. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Microsoft Edge does not launch like a normal Win32 application.   However, you can download a small application that *will* launch Edge from a normal EXE file.

There are several "Edge Launch" application available...  I wrote one.   Take a look at this article to see if this is something that you'd like to use:

http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/EdgeLaunch.html

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work in Sandboxie... :(

Comment: Interesting... I use a similar product (Acronis "Try and Decide"), and I never had trouble with launching Edge (the normal way).

Answer (score 2):

Edge already runs in a [sandbox provided by Windows](http://recxltd.blogspot.in/2012/03/windows-8-app-container-security-notes.html) with the help of the [User Account Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control). There is **no need sandbox Edge**. Also the Store apps can't be started directly by clicking on the exe.

Comment: To add to magicandre1981's answer, the _sandbox_ Windows creates is called **AppContainer**. More info: [link](http://recxltd.blogspot.in/2012/03/windows-8-app-container-security-notes.html).

Comment: @PrashantKumar96 - Its also not a sandbox in the same sense that Sandboxie is, but of course, Microsoft has made it known they want to go to a model closer to that for all applications in the future.  I am not not away that Sandboxie could even launch UWP, because its entirely function, is that its recieving and then forwarding all library functions but UWP uses entirely different functions.